# Unable to import 'flask_login'

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

`flask_login` was successfully installed, but

```py
from flask_login import UserMixin
```

gives me

```
Unable to import 'flask_login'
```

error on mac. However, on my linux cloud VM, no such error shows up. I need your ideas to get this fixed on mac. I am using VS code.

```py
from flask import Flask,render_template,url_for
from flask_login import UserMixin
from forms import RegistrationForm,LoginForm
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

on linux I have python version 3.8.16
`pip show flask_login` results:

```
name: Flask-Login, version:0.6.3
```

on mac I have python version 3.9.13
`pip show flask_login` results:

```
name: Flask-Login, version:0.6.3
```

I copied same code to the linux environment, no issues.

Comment: on mac, if you run the following commands, what do you see? 1. `which python` 2. `which pip`, your python and pip does not have same source, that is the reason for the error.

Comment: check on mac, make source you use python env or not, your command python and pip is same path

Comment: Thank you TanThien, simpleApp , issue was solved. Was due to virtual environment conflict as you mentioned it.